# Failed to create a materialized view log on master table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, materialized-views

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON acquisitions
TABLESPACE users
WITH PRIMARY KEY
INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
```

I am  trying to create a materialized view log on my master table acquisition. The master table is in the same database as materialized view. I am trying to satisfy all the criteria 
to reproduce commit on refresh .Creating a mv log is one of those. But I got this error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Advanced replication
00439. 00000 -  "feature not enabled: %s"
*Cause:    The specified feature is not enabled.
*Action:   Do not attempt to use this feature.
```

I am using ORACLE 11g. Is this is bug in ORACLE 11g ?

Answer (score 0):

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON sales

WITH ROWID, SEQUENCE(amount_sold, time_id, prod_id)

INCLUDNG NEW VALUES; **strong text**

try this example ,may be it helps